# What semantic notions underlie the Ancient Greek 'Anacrusis' and its meaning as 'pickup note'?

Tags: terminology, anacrusis

> [[Etymonline :]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Anacrusis)  "unstressed syllable at the beginning of a verse," 1833,
> Latinized
> from Greek anakrousis "a pushing back," of a ship, "backing water,"
> from anakrouein "to push back, stop short, check," from *ana* "back" (see [ana-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ana-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *krouein* "to strike,"
> from PIE *kreue- (2) "to push, strike"

In what sense can a pickup note be judged as pushing back or up (the definition of 'anacrusis' in Ancient Greek)?  (Nescient of poetry) I do not understand Wikipedia's [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacrusis)) of the semantic shift from poetry:

> #### Poetry
>
> In poetry, a set of extrametrical syllables at the beginning of a verse is said to stand in anacrusis (Ancient Greek: ἀνάκρουσις "pushing up"). The technique is seen Old English poetry,[1] and in lines of iambic pentameter, the technique applies a variation on the typical pentameter line causing it to appear at first glance as trochaic.
>
> #### Music
>
> [...] The musical term is inferred from the terminology of poetry, where it refers to one or more first but unstressed syllables of a lyrical verse. [...]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see any semantic shift at all between an anacrusis in poetry and in music: it's one and the same thing, pretty much.  Poetic speech has rhythm, perhaps not always as strict as music commonly is, but there's no place you can really draw a line between poetry and song.  And the anacrusis, or pickup, or *Auftakt* as we say here in Austria, is, as the wiki article says, an unaccented tone or syllable or beat or more that occur before the first accented beat of the rhythm.

Comment: & even the simplest has an anacrusis - any Limerick... "There **was** a young **wo**man from **Leeds**, which is a 6/8 or swing, just the same as [without anacrusis] "Nellie the elephant packed her trunk..."

Comment: Maybe it's the "pushing back" as these days we'd be inclined to say that was 'bringing forwards'. I think of pushing back as leaving your timing a tad late for emphasis